# How to groupby a data frame in pyspark by a column and get a dictionary with that column as key and list of records as its value?

Tags: python, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, aws-glue

I have a dataframe like this -

```
-RECORD 0-------------------------------------------

 id                          | 11           
 order_number                | 254                  
 order_date                  | 2021-03-09           
 store_id                    | abc6            
 employee_code               | 6921_abc40    
 customer_name               | harvey 
 contact_number              | 353          
 address                     | foo 
 locality                    | foo               
 postal_code                 | 5600082332             
 order_info                  | info
 amount                      | 478.8                
 payment_type                | null                 
 timeA                       | 2021-03-10 01:34:26
 timeB                       | 2021-03-10 01:35:26  
             
-RECORD 1-------------------------------------------

 id                          | 12            
 order_number                | 2272                 
 order_date                  | 2021-03-09           
 store_id                    | abc666             
 employee_code               | 66_abc55               
 customer_name               | mike        
 contact_number              | 98          
 address                     | bar
 locality                    | bar
 postal_code                 | 11000734332              
 order_info                  | info
 amount_to_be_collected      | 0.34                 
 payment_type                | null                 
 timeA                       | 2021-03-10 00:18:04  
 timeB                       | 2021-03-10 03:21:06
```

I want to do the following -

Groupby the records by employee_code and get a dictionary in return which would be something like this -

```
{"emp_code": [Record0, Record1, ....]}
```

i.e., the employee code as the key and a list of all records of that employee as the value.

I am writing a Gluejob for this. I can do this programmatically by looping through all the records and getting the desired dictionary, but this will take a lot of time. I want to know if there is a way to achieve this result by using some higher order pyspark functions?

Answer (score 0):

### Using maps

You can create a map that has a key based on `employee_code` and a struct or array as the value as:

```
df = df.select(map(col("employee_code"), struct("order_number", "order_date",,)).alias("complex_map"))
```

Then you can query it using `selectExpr` as a map:

```
df.selectExpr("complex_map['employee_code']").show(2)
```

---

### Alternative with structs:

For this you'll need to do some transformations into ComplexTypes before `grouping by` them which basically transforms the structure from sth like:

```
DataFrame[order_number: string, employee_code: string, ....]>
```

into sth like this:

```
DataFrame[employee_code: string, complex: struct<order_number:string,contact_number:int>]>
```

That can be done using the `struct` function from `from pyspark.sql.functions import struct`:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import struct

df.select(col("employee_code"), struct("order_number", "order_date", ...).alias("orders"))
```

Once you have them in that kind of struct you can perform a group by and use  the aggregation function collect_list:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import struct, collect_list

df.select(col("employee_code"), struct("order_number", "order_date", ...).alias("orders")).groupBy("employee_code").agg(collect_list("orders").alias("orders")
```

Then you can select individual cols within the struct as:

```
df.select(col("orders.order_number"))
```

Or even filtering them by:

```
df.select(col("employee_code")).where(col("orders.order_number") > 100)
```

If you want be back at what you were take a look at the `explode` function, which takes a column of arrays and creates one row (with the rest of the values as duplicated)

Comment: Hi, what if my record has around 100 columns, so while using the struct function, will I have to explicitly mention all the columns' name while doing this?

Comment: You can use the selectExpr("select *) api then